# How to check if a text is in web page in Robot Framework and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, robotframework

I'm currently creating an automation test for a website and I want to check if a text(s) is in the page. I could use the keyword '**Page should contain**' to check; however, I want it to be a little more specific on having it check specifically where the text exist in the page. Is there a way I can have it check if a specific div contains the text?

Comment: More and better choices - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242291/robotframework-how-to-check-text-on-page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily do this with a built-in Selenium2Library tags.

For a **partial match** use this:

```
Element Should Contain    locator    expected_text
```

For an **exact match** use this:

```
Element Text Should Be    locator    expected_text
```

Answer (score 4):

If your HTML code is something like:
Your `div` tag and need to find `FindMe`

```
<div class="gwt-Label">This FindMe DIV</div>
```

Then you can find `"FindMe"` text like:

```
//div[@class='gwt-Label'][contains(string(),'FindMe')]
```