# RobotFramework, how to check text on page

Tags: text, robotframework

if there appears text on a page after hitting a button.

the only thing it is in  is a class, like so:

```
<label class="err">2 van de 3 velden  Eiwit, Koolhydraten, Vet  zijn leeg.</label>
```

with what should you verify?

I tried:

```
Page Should Contain Textfield    err
```

but that's not the way to go I think

```
    *** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Browser Implicit Wait    5
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
    Login Page Should Be Open

Login Page Should Be Open
    Title Should Be    Hippe testautomatisering getest i.c.m. testtechnieken

Go To Login Page
    Go To    ${LOGIN URL}
    Login Page Should Be Open

Input Username
    [Arguments]    ${username} 
    Input Text    voedselnaam    ${username}

Input Password
    [Arguments]    ${password}
    Input Text    Eenheid    ${password}
    Input Text    Kcal    ${password}
    Input Text    Eiwit    ${password}

Submit Credentials
    Click Element   getdata    
    page should contain  //label[@class='err']  2 van de 3 velden Eiwit, Koolhydraten, Vet zijn leeg.


Welcome Page Should Be Open
    Location Should Be    ${LOGIN URL}
    Title Should Be    Welcome Page
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are various options choose which suites you most

***Using Keywords***

1. If you want exact text match then use

   ```
   Element Text Should Be    //label[@class='err']    2 van de 3 velden  Eiwit, Koolhydraten, Vet  zijn leeg.
   ```
2. If you want substring in text

   ```
   Element Should Contain    //label[@class='err']    velden
   ```
3. It waits until the locator with text appears on page , I think another option to suffice to serve you verify text

   ```
   Wait Until Element Contains    locator        text
   ```
4. This will verify text on entire page so it may be present multiple times on page or only single time

   ```
   Wait Until Page Contains        text_you_want_to_verify_on_page
   ```

***Using Locators***

to match complete text

```
//label[text()="2 van de 3 velden  Eiwit, Koolhydraten, Vet  zijn leeg."]
```

to match partial text

```
//label[contains(text(),'velden')]
```

and pass it to one of keyword which verifies element on page.
for more option you can [explore here](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Element%20Text%20Should%20Be)