# How to verify text but except some text in line using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have to verify text that present on web page but in the text line have dynamic wording that I don't know how to verify this situation.

```
    Wait Until Element Contains    &{verScript}[Script]    Test automate for 50,000 time   timeout=60s
```

I want to verify text "Test automate for 50,000 time" but 50,000 is dynamic value. I don't want to verify 50,000 in this locator and can it whatever for this value in line.

Can any help me please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242977/5400362 look at this answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**using set**

```
@{queryResultsA}=    split string     Test automate for 50,000 time
@{queryResultsB}=    split string     Test automate for XX,XXX time

${z} =  Evaluate    (set(${queryResultsA}) - set(${queryResultsB}))

## here ${z} will be 50,000
```

**Using keyword**

will return all lines on the page which are matching given string. the following keyword will return Lines as one string concatenated back together with newlines

```
Get Lines Containing String    Test automate for
```

**for more keywords**

which [match partial and full text/strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242977/5400362)

[using regex and pattern matching](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Lines%20Matching%20Pattern)