# How to get substring in the given string from Robot Framework?

Tags: automation, robotframework, web-testing

Given String  "Showing 1 to 10 of 3,311 entries". I need to get the 3,311 separately form that string. I can use this `${Number} =    Get Substring ${countString}    19    24` but here problem is index was changed.

Comment: Have a look at regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Split String` keyword and separate the each part of string by `${SPACE}`
Additionaly I removed `,` from the number just in case you need it. Slightly different way to achieve same - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57786634/5400362

```
*** Variable ***
${string1}=        Showing 1 to 10 of 3,311 entries

*** Testcases ***
Get Number From String

@{list_string}=     split string    ${string1}      ${SPACE}
log             ${list_string}[5]
${num}=         evaluate       '${list_string}[5]'.replace(',','')
```

**output**

[image]