# How can I extract just YYYY-MM-DD from the retrieved variable?

Tags: robotframework

If I have:

```
${time} = OperatingSystem.Get Modified Time @{Files}[${i}]
${onlyDate} = ???
```

How can I easily just get the YYYY-MM-DD from ${time} instead of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get substring in the given string from Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826693/how-to-get-substring-in-the-given-string-from-robot-framework). Also see the [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Substring) substring documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this with DateTime Library :
`${date} =     Convert Date    ${date}     result_format=%Y-m%-d%`
Refer more at - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Date%20formats