# Robotframework : How can I have this kind of result => Page MUST (and not SHOULD) contain element

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to RobotFramework and I would have some help for my issue.

On a page, I would like to verify that a word is present on a locator. I have used the `Page Should Contain Element` keyword and it works partially : indeed, the elements which contains the word is found, but there isn't an error when the others elements (same type) don't contain this word.

Example (I work on a list of sell):
The page contains many locators of this type :

```
//*[@class="resultats mode_liste ng-scope"]/div[@ng-repeat="annonce in resultats.data.annonces "]//h2/a/strong[@class="ng-binding"]
```

- A "div" element contains "locator1" which contains "House"
- A "div" element contains "locator1" which contains "House"
- A "div" element contains "locator1" which contains "Box"
- Etc...

So I have written the Keyword

```
Page Should Contain Element    //*[@class="resultats mode_liste ng-scope"]/div[@ng-repeat="annonce in resultats.data.annonces "]//h2/a/strong[@class="ng-binding"][contains(., "House")]
```

but the result is not what I expected (error if another word than "House" is founded on the locator1)

And I would like to have the following result: All the locator1 elements MUST contain the word "House". If the locator1 contains a different word, then the test must fail.

Comment: I think I must use a loop but i don't know how to code in Python.
The loop says "for each element A, the word "Box" must be found".

Comment: these are a sum of options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242291/robotframework-how-to-check-text-on-page

Answer (score 0):

According to the Library documentation, you can set a "limit" parameter which allows you to set the amount of elements to check for on the page

E.g. if you wanted to check the element appears twice on the page then you can set limit to 2

```
Page Should Contain Element    //*[@class="resultats mode_liste ng-scope"]/div[@ng-repeat="annonce in resultats.data.annonces "]//h2/a/strong[@class="ng-binding"][contains(., "House")]  limit=2
```

From doc:

"The limit argument can used to define how many elements the page should contain. When limit is None (default) page can contain one or more elements. When limit is a number, page must contain same number of elements."

Having said that, if you're using an older version of the Library, you may need to use a different keyword like "Xpath Should Match X Times" but it is deprecated in new version

The other issue with not failing based on other words in the element is because the Xpath you're using is specifically looking at just elements that contain the text "House" therefore the other elements will be ignored completely when running this.

If you wanted to check to ensure that no other text is contained in elements and you know what they would be then you could use additional keyword

```
Page Should Not Contain Element  //*[@class="resultats mode_liste ng-scope"]/div[@ng-repeat="annonce in resultats.data.annonces "]//h2/a/strong[@class="ng-binding"][contains(., "Box")]
```

However if you will not know what the text will be then you may need to approach this differently by getting the web element text values and cycling through them in a loop and checking the text of each one matches "House"

It would look something like this:

```
Check Element Contains Text 'House' 
   @{elements}=  Get Webelements  //*[@class="resultats mode_liste ng-scope"]/div[@ng-repeat="annonce in resultats.data.annonces "]//h2/a/strong[@class="ng-binding"]
   FOR  ${element}  IN  @{elements}
     ${text}=  Get Text  ${element}
     Should Be Equal As Strings  ${text}  House
   END
```

I'm unable to test it to be absolutely sure though.